# How to store session flask

Tags: python, flask, session

we are developing card game and there we should create a room with one user. All data about user and room must stored in session. Without sending data to database. Anyone has idea's how should i store data. And where should store it. And after 2 player connect to the game. I should it post to database.
Sorry, but i have no idea how to do it. If someone have code examples. Can you share it

Comment: I don't think someone has code examples, but if you had tried anything then you may share that with us. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think first create a flask project and decide on the database you will use. Create a model about users and export it to db. (i.e. migrate) . Then create the game model and determine the relationship between the users table and the game table. The information you share is limited, the most important point that comes to my mind with this information is the session management of the game and the user. The user is always present, the session is active when he enters the game and drops when he exits. You can write a scenario based on your own game about Session. With the alias given to the user's session, you can perform crud operations during the game according to the scenario.

Sample Code For "how to store session"

```
session['sample_user'] = value
session['sample_user2'] = value
# session keep value as a dict and you can use theese value
session.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask has module. You can use something like this:

```
from flask import session
```

and then you can use syntax for example:

```
if "logged" not in session:
```

etc.

It's hard to give specific advice if you don't share the code you have.